# Rotation of plane about a line

Tags: 3d

The plane denoted by $$P_1 : 4x + 7y + 4z + 81 = 0$$ is rotated through a right angle about its line of intersection with the plane $$P_2 : 5x + 3y + 10z = 25$$. If the plane in its new position be denoted by $P$, and the distance of this plane from the origin is $\sqrt{d}$ then find $d$.

I tried

The equation of line of intersection is

$$(4x + 7y + 4z + 81) + k(4x+7y+4z+81) = 0$$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The equation written by the OP is of plane passing through both the given planes .

The dot product of this equation and of initial equation is zero .

By doing this we get k=$-1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the line of intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

**Hints:**

(1) $(4,7,4)$ is a normal vector of $P_1$.

(2) If $v$ is a direction of $r$, (do you know how to find such direction?), then $(a,b,c)=v\times (4,7,4)$ could be a normal vector of $P$ (why?).

(3) Find a point that belongs to $P_1$ and $r$ and it will belong to $P$, say $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ (why?).

(4) An equation for $P$ is given by $ax+by+cz+f=0$, where $ax_0+by_0+cz_0+f=0$.

(5) Now you can calculate such $d$.

Comment: In second hint how to find the direction

Comment: You have to solve the system given by the equations of $P_1$ and $P_2$. Every point that satisfies these equations belongs to $r$.

Comment: How to rotate the plane

Comment: We solved the rotation problem when we said that $(a,b,c)=v\times (4,7,4)$ could be a normal vector of $P$, because it's orthogonal to both $v$ and $(4,7,4)$.